# External CSS does not work when put into a zip folder

Tags: html, css

I have a folder called HTML, where I can store my HTML and CSS files. The CSS and HTML always work in the HTML folder.

However, I created a zip folder inside the HTML folder, and put some HTML and CSS files in there. Now, when I click on an HTML project (in the zip folder), the CSS doesn't apply.

I did not change any of my code when changing folders.

[image]

That is what the normal HTML code looks like.

[image]

This is my zip file, "myfixedpage" is the HTML and "fixed" is the CSS.

[image]

That is what happens when I click the "myfixedpage" HTML code. All CSS formatting is gone.
Help would be appreciated.

Here is part of the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fixed.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Fixed Layout </title>
    </head>
```

As stated before, though, I did not change any code in either HTML or CSS when changing folders.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it still happen on a hard refresh of your page? ctrl + shift + r

Comment: You just cannot do that... even if it'd work serving files locally with `file://` (it won't), it'd never work in a real web server... a "Zip folder" is not actually a folder, but a file.

Comment: @DanLeach Sadly, yes it still does. Not sure what really could've gone wrong here...

Comment: @JordiNebot I've created a zip file before and added HTML and CSS files in it. So far, there has never been an error. I'm not currently planning to make any websites on the real web.

Comment: @FruDe when you say zip folder do you mean a file called something.zip or do you just mean a normal folder. If you are putting your html and css in a .zip file then it won't work

Comment: @DanLeach I mean a .zip file. It's worked before, so I'm not sure why it's not working now.

Comment: Can you try <link href="content.zip#fixed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> - just replace content.zip with the name of your zip file

Comment: @DanLeach Sadly, still doesn't work. I'm starting to think that the only thing that could've gone wrong is some sort of spelling error, but not sure yet.

Comment: Check your browser console to see if you get a 404 or resource not loading message. At least then you'll know if it's finding the stylesheet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213366/discussion-between-frude-and-dan-leach).